# Multi select RecyclerView is Not Working in android properly

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

When I am scrolling at that time the position is changing of view holder when I am coming back to same View. I want to highlight my view holder when item is clicked and for second time it backs to normal.
This is my Full adater class. Please help me out.

```
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    int rowIndex=-1;
    private int checkedPosition = 0;
    public List<Contacts> cont;
    Contacts list;
    private ArrayList<Contacts> arraylist;

//constructor
    public ContactAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, List<Contacts> items) {
        this.layoutInflater = inflater;
        this.cont = items;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(cont);
    }
//create View
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

//Bind Holder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
        list = cont.get(position);
        String name = (list.getName());
            holder.cont_name.setText(name);
            holder.cont_number.setText(list.getPhone());

        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(list.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    cont.get(position).setSelected(!cont.get(position).isSelected());
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(list.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });

            if (list.isSelected()){
                System.out.println("selected : " + position);
            }
    }



    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cont.size();
    }
```

My View holder class

```
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView cont_name;
        public TextView cont_number;
        public LinearLayout contact_select_layout, mainLL;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.setIsRecyclable(false);
            cont_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_name);
            cont_number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cont_number);
            contact_select_layout =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_select_layout);
            mainLL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLL);
        }

    }
```

my recyclerView Call activity snippet

```
   adapter = new ContactAdapter(inflater, selectUsers);
            rvContacts.setHasFixedSize(true);
            rvContacts.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
            rvContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Recyclerview has a build-in **reuse** mechanism. A specific ViewHolder actually show different data when scrolling. In your `onClick ` method, modify data and call `notifyItemChange`, rather than access view directly.

Comment: Can you post your whole adapter file?

Comment: I have tried that method also notifyItemChange. But is not working still.

Comment: @GuanHongHuang I have updated my adapter class. Please Let me know

Comment: @HarshDoshi delete this line `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`

Comment: I removed that line, but I want to select multiple contact. In one click the on click is not working. @GuanHongHuang

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    list.setSelected(!list.isSelected());
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(list.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);

                }
            });
```

to

```
  holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    cont.get(position).setSelected(!cont.get(position).isSelected());
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(list.isSelected() ? Color.CYAN : Color.WHITE);
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            });
```

Hope this helps.